# Camera2 RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete

Tags: android-camera2

After I used camera then closed it with the following code, this error happened:

> Camera2 RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete

```
try {
    mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
    if (null != mCameraCaptureSession) {
        mCameraCaptureSession.close();
        mCameraCaptureSession = null;
    }
    if (null != mImageReader) {
        mImageReader.close();
        mImageReader = null;
    }
    if (null != cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        mIsOpen = false;
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
} finally {
    mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
}
```

Use the imageReader to get the image.